# Solution method used for Scipy solve_banded matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

Does anyone know what method `scipy.linalg.solve_banded` uses to solve the system of equations?  The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve_banded.html) does not state the solution method used by the function.  Usually the [Thomas algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm), a.k.a. TDMA, is used for these types of systems but I was wondering if this Scipy function uses some other solution method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Github code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/linalg/basic.py) shows that `scipy` uses the `lapack` routine `gbsv()` to solve this. You can read about `gbsv()` [here](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/dd/dc2/dgbsv_8f.html) and [here](http://apfel.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/~lehn/FLENS/cxxlapack/netlib/lapack/dgbsv.f.html).

I am not sure if this the same as the Thomas algorithm. Looks like both use LU decomposition, though.

Comment: Ok, I'll check out the link for `gbsv()`. I edited my question to include a link for the Thomas algorithm.